# how to append to a JEditorPane?

Tags: java, swing, append, jtextfield, jeditorpane

now i am making a calculator and want to append the problems and thier answers into a JEditorPane. I looked around and found a post that says that a one can append to a JTextField, but when i try to append to a JTextField i still get the same error

```
Calculator.java:46: error: cannot find symbol
        answerField.append("5");
                   ^
```

my code:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
String mathProblem = enterField.getText();
answerField.append(mathProblem + "=");
answerField.append(solve(mathProblem));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a work around to append text.
1.  make it a `JTextPane`
2. append basicly says sets the text to what is in there + new entry, so it would look like
this `setText(textField.getText() + enteredText);`

Code:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
String mathProblem = enterField.getText();
answerField.setText(answerField.getText() + "\r" + mathProblem + "=");
answerField.setText(answerField.getText() + solve(mathProblem));
}
```